# Show summary row and add it to the end of excel export

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, export

I'm trying to create summary row for my GridView which sums my quantity for current page and for all records seperately.

```
            <?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'layout' => "{summary}\n{items}\n<div align='right'>{pager}</div>",
            //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'showPageSummary' => true,
            'pageSummaryFunc' => GridView::F_SUM,
            'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

                [
                    'class' => DataColumn::className(),
                    'attribute' => 'updated_at',
                    'format' => 'raw',
                    'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column){
                        return date('Y-m-d', $model->updated_at);
                    },
                ],
                [
                    'label' => 'Ilość',
                    'attribute'=>'quantity',    
                    'pageSummary' => true,
                    'value'=> function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                        return ($model->quantity) ? $model->quantity : '';
                    },

                ],
            ],
        ]); ?>
```

At the end i want to export sum for all records to my excel sheet at the bottom of my gridColumns. My export widget looks like:

```
        $dataProviderAll->setSort([
        'defaultOrder' => ['updated_at' => SORT_ASC]
    ]);

    echo ExportMenu::widget([
            'container' => ['class' => 'btn-group pull-right', 'role' => 'group'],
            'dataProvider' => $dataProviderAll,
            'columns' => $gridColumns,
            'filename' => date('Y-m-d') . '_raport',
            'target' => ExportMenu::TARGET_SELF,
            'showConfirmAlert' => false,
            'showColumnSelector' => false,
            'fontAwesome' => true,
            'dropdownOptions' => [
                    'label' => 'Eksportuj dane',
                    'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-md'
            ],
            'exportConfig' => [
                    ExportMenu::FORMAT_HTML => null,
                    ExportMenu::FORMAT_TEXT => null,
                    ExportMenu::FORMAT_EXCEL => null,
                    ExportMenu::FORMAT_PDF => null
            ]
    ]);
    ?>
```

All columns of model are already exported, but i need to add summary row for some of them into created excel file.

Im getting now error like this: `Setting unknown property: kartik\grid\GridView::pageSummaryFunc`

Does someone know how can I get this result?

Comment: I have fixed part where I wanted to get sum per page by replacing class column from yii to kartik.

Comment: Add your own answer so the rest can know what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed part where I wanted to get sum per page by replacing class column from yii to kartik. –